# Entity framework core attach/update for child objects

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using entity framework core 2.1 and my database context contains of the follwing classes

```
public class MultiStringSetting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<MultiString> Values { get; set; }
}

public class MultiString
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Consider the following: I have 3 `MultiString` objects in my database with id's 1, 2 and 3. My current `MultiStringSetting` has `MultiString` 1 in its `Values`. What i would like to do now is set the `Values` of my `MultiStringSetting` to 2 and 3, without removing `MultiString` 1 from my database. How can i achieve this? I tried some things like `attach` and `update` but both had no success for me.

Bonus question: What if i have the same scenario as above however i now have a list of `MultiStringSetting` and i want to update them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by first getting all the objects from the database and then manually removing the objects using `.Remove()`. When all references are removed I then added them back with the new objects using `.Add()`.